# Ruby on Rails 3: script/server --path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Did option --path stayed in rails 3 or not? If not how do I test installation into sub uri?

Thanks

Comment: ./script/server in rails 2.x had option --path which forced app to be server from given prefix